# Genshi: if/else

Tags: python, pylons, genshi

How do I do a simple if/else in the Genshi templating language?

I've found [this ticket](http://genshi.edgewall.org/ticket/134), which seems to suggest that Genshi doesn't support if/else, but it doesn't really explain what it supports instead.

I basically just want something like this:

```
  <py:if test="c.row.currency">
  ${c.row.currency.upper()}
  <py:else>
  ${c.row.dataset_.currency.upper()} 
  </py:if>
```

But I get 'Bad Directive: else'. Should I be using [py:choose instead](http://genshi.edgewall.org/wiki/Documentation/xml-templates.html#id2)? I can't really get my head around how to use it for an if/else condition.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Currently, you can not if do else constructs in Genshi, and as far as I'm aware, there are no plans to add it. Instead, like you mentioned, use py:choose. The following is how you use py:choose as a type of if/else construct:

```
<py:choose ...>
  <py:when test="...">
    ${c.row.currency.upper()}
  </py:when>
  <py:otherwise>
   ${c.row.currency.upper()}
  </py:otherwise>
</py:choose>
```

Comment: That works, thank you! I just used <py:choose> as the opening tag.